# Can React Native Navigator deal with this condition?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

For example, there're 2 pages (A and B) in an app.

Use `Navigator.push()` from A to B (`route stack` should be `[A, B]` at present), then what should I do to realize this scene:

**Navigator to a new page C from page B and make sure that the view state of C is same as A (make sure that A still in the `route stack` equal to `route stack = [A, B, C]` ).**

I shouldn't simply use `Navigator.push(routeA)` because it will re-render page A. And if I combine `Navigator.jumpBack()` and `Navigator.jumpForward()`, there is not a new `route` push to the `route stack`.

ps: In my project, page B is a list of search result, I need to hold this page's view state (eg. the scroll location of a `ScrollView`). I think that using `redux` to save the "view state" to `store` may solve this problem, but it is not a essential method.

Thanks! English novice :)